# Auto create database in SQL Server upon user login

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I need to automatically create a database (and create tables, etc) when a user logs on to SQL Server using Windows Authentication. If the username is `smith`, a new database called `smith` will be created, and the user will have the full access to that database.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Do able, but it's a significant effort to write, test, debug and insure that it's both safe and secure.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Have you considered creating a schema inside an existing database instead? What if two smiths log in?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found the solution - there is a logon trigger. So I can create the database and load data in the trigger.

Comment: @user3019981 You can also make your entire SQL Server effectively unusable if you make any of a number of mistakes even once.  *SQL Logon triggers are NOT for the uninitiated.*  They are dangerous and tricky, and that's why none of us volunteered it at first.

Answer (score 0):

First question would be why do you want to create a new database each time someone logs in. Why don't you reuse an existing database? What happens if someone logs in 1000 times - you will create a lot of databases!

To create the database you can use commands like this (in a batch script)

```
if exists (select * from sys.syslogins where name='$(dbname)')
  drop login $(dbname);
GO

if exists(select * from sys.databases where name='$(dbname)')
  drop database $(dbname);
GO

create database $(dbname);
GO

EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'bulkadmin'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'dbcreator'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'diskadmin'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'processadmin'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'securityadmin'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'serveradmin'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'setupadmin'
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '$(dbloginname)', 'sysadmin'
```